# Only in WORDPRESS: REST.php ---> Unable to decode supplied JSON

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, json

This is my first post for CiviCRM.

Hi to all.

I have seen others post related and nowadays the problem remain.

Different from this post: 
[REST API: Unable to decode supplied JSON](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6585/rest-api-unable-to-decode-supplied-json)
 - with wordpress I got always the same response "**Unable to decode supplied JSON**".

I tried clear installation with Joomla and also Backdrop, and both works correctly.

I am not a good programmer but I tried to do some stuff myself, here you what I prepared on my little server:

WordPress+CiviCRM with the problem: [link clear installation](http://144.91.105.68/cms/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&api_key=a42bfc2b33cf13184711bff14fe1fb19&key=a42bfc2b33cf13184711bff14fe1fb19&json=%7B%22sequential%22:1%7D)

WordPress+CiviCRM fixed myself: [custom](http://144.91.105.68/cms/cust/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&api_key=a42bfc2b33cf13184711bff14fe1fb19&key=a42bfc2b33cf13184711bff14fe1fb19&json=%7B%22sequential%22:1%7D)

Here you what I modified to the file REST.php...

after line 326

```
    if (array_key_exists('json', $requestParams) && $requestParams['json'][0] == "{") {
      $params = json_decode($requestParams['json'], TRUE);
```

my modification start here

```
      $new_requestParams= $requestParams['json'];

      $new_requestParams= str_replace("\\", "", $new_requestParams);
      $new_requestParams= str_replace("\\", "", $new_requestParams);

      $params = json_decode($new_requestParams, TRUE);
```

I practically saw a lot of "\" before the JSON DECODE.

So removing this "\" now works regularly.

If you wish can check directly on both sites:
Clear ----> http://144.91.105.68/cms/wordpress

Custom ---> http://144.91.105.68/cms/cust/wordpress

The user and password are both same:   **admin** / **admin**

And also siteKey and api_key are always:  **a42bfc2b33cf13184711bff14fe1fb19**

Regards Roberto T.

Answer (score 2):

The correct endpoint for WordPress is `wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest`. Its documented in the developer manual, see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/wp-rest/#endpoints.   When you just copy the URL that is suggested in the API explorer you are left in the dark.